# I want to design a context free grammar for the following

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars

This below language

$$L = \{ w \in \{a, b\}^n : \lvert w\rvert \text{ mod } 3 = 0 \}$$
where $n \geq0$.

Comment: Could you design a CFG for a language where each string had length exactly three? If so, it's just a tiny modification to get what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this seems very much like homework, i will give you a little Hint, taking as example a sub-case of your language:

The ***GFC*** for the string $a^3b^3$ is the following:

$S ⇒ aSb$

$aSb ⇒ aaSbb$

$aaSbb ⇒ aaaSbbb$

$aaaSbbb ⇒ aaabbb$

You can take the above as a starting point from which to adapt the grammar to your case.

Comment: Thank you very much